# Foreign key constraint error on Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to have this third class `noticeTime` be constrained to the foreign key `email`. I am using the same syntax that worked for the 2nd class `location`, but when I use it on `noticeTime` it throws an error:

`Exception Value:   no such column: setupNotifications_noticetime.email_id`

Here is the code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

class email(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email`

class location(models.Model):
    email = models.ForeignKey(email)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.zip_code

class noticeTime(models.Model):
    email = models.ForeignKey(email)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.time
```

here is admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from setupNotifications.models import email
from setupNotifications.models import location
from setupNotifications.models import noticeTime


admin.site.register(email)
admin.site.register(location)
admin.site.register(noticeTime)
```

I'm using the sqlite database

Comment: Code you posted won't give you error that you mentioned. Post the complete code.

Comment: Its a django app so there are a lot of other files that are referenced, not sure how I would post all those

Comment: I guess you'll find it within your views.py accessing noticeTime-Model? Could you post that file?

Comment: virews.py: `from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.`

Comment: Where do you access `setupNotifications`...or better...where do you get the error / what are you doing?

Comment: Using the django admin interface

Comment: Is there anything within your `admin.py`? *something more than `#create stuff here` ;-)

Comment: Yep, just references to include the three classes in the admin interface

Comment: please update/edit your question and add the content of your `admin.py`

Comment: updated. Also I see a lot of down-votes, can someone share what about the question was not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is that you ran syncdb, assuming that it would alter the table to match your model change. Unfortunately, it does not do that. There are some separate tools available, such as South, which can help with database migrations.